# Laravel DB Connection without hitting any query

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, laravel-5.3

Currently i am facing issue that on home page loading LARAVEL creates database connection even without hitting any query to database. Last week we got DDOS attack on website and our database went down, cause of this our users were unable to access our website.

So please help me to prevent database connection without hitting any query

Thanks

Comment: This should not happen. Try installing the [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to see what queries are executed on the homepage.